# Vimfiler (a plugin): how to open .doc file using MS Word

Tags: external-command, macvim

I have a question regarding a plugin called [Vimfiler](https://github.com/Shougo/vimfiler.vim). What I want is to open a .doc/.docx file using MS Word from **Vimfiler**. For this, I added the following

```
call vimfiler#set_execute_file('doc,docx', '/Applications/Microsoft Word.app')
```

to `.vimrc`. Even if I pressed `Return` after choosing a `.doc` file on Vimfiler, MS Word did not start. I also attempted to select the `open` action by pressing `a` after choosing a `.doc` file, but the same result as before.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

MacVim on El Capitan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, it is likely OSX already associates `.doc` and `.docx` files with MS Word. So you can use that to your advantage, using `vimfiler_execute_system_associated`, which is mapped to `x`:

```
x                       <Plug>(vimfiler_execute_system_associated)
```

Just pressing `x` on the filename should be enough.

Comment: Wow! `x` worked! It worked even without the mapping you suggested. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Word or Windows so I tried solving your issue with Libreoffice and `.odt` files. The following code seems to work:

```
call vimfiler#set_execute_file('odt', 'libreoffice')
augroup vimfiler_mapping
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vimfiler nmap <buffer> x <Plug>(vimfiler_execute_vimfiler_associated)
augroup END
```

Maybe you could tweak the code for your needs:

```
call vimfiler#set_execute_file('doc', 'path/to/MS Word')
augroup vimfiler_mapping
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vimfiler nmap <buffer> x <Plug>(vimfiler_execute_vimfiler_associated)
augroup END
```

The autocmd installs a buffer-local mapping on the `x` key whenever you open a buffer whose filetype is `vimfiler`.
And as [muru](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6414/vimfiler-a-plugin-how-to-open-doc-file-using-ms-word#comment10112_6415) explained in the comment, the call to the function `vimfiler#set_execute_file()` appends a new item in the dictionary `g:vimfiler_execute_file_list` whose values are command names designated to open the files with the extension stored inside the associated keys.

For more information, see:

```
:help vimfiler#set_execute_file()
:help <Plug>(vimfiler_execute_vimfiler_associated)
:help g:vimfiler_execute_file_list
```

Comment: You should probably map to some other key instead of `<cr>` (maybe `x`?) , and `vimfiler#set_execute_file` appends to this dictionary, so perhaps the function call is more appropriate.

Comment: @muru You are right, the call to the function is a better solution as it appends to the dictionary instead of overwriting it. I also changed the key to `x`.

Comment: @muru Sorry I deleted it because I found yours much simpler and more efficient. I didn't realize there was already a built-in mapping for what the author of the question wanted. I've undeleted it now.

Comment: Well, `vimfiler_execute_system_associated` serves a different purpose. With `vimfiler_associated` (which is what OP and you are interested in), you don't have to change settings which might affect other programs - the association is purely within Vim. With `system_associated`, a change in association affects other programs as well (and has to be done outside Vim).